# When to use logger.info in sl4j

Tags: java, logging

For my application logs for a REST server, I'd like to log some details about each http request. I'm using sl4j. Should I use logger.debug or logger.info

More generally what sort of things should be logged in logger.info?

Comment: It might [interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6860186/5934037). Short and concise.

Answer (score 1):

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html defines the intended meanings of the levels and also explains that the ordering is OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG and ALL.

INFO is `informational messages that highlight the progress of the application at coarse-grained level.`. This sounds like what you are describing; you want to know what happened in the normal run of events

DEBUG is `fine-grained informational events that are most useful to debug an application.`. I reserve this for debugging, ie. something has gone wrong and you need to log something fine-grained, not just the error. I find it rare to put this in at the beginning of a code-base and more likely to go into a patch-release if an unreproducible issue is occurring in an environment. But if you can anticipate those kind of errors and what fine-grained information you require, maybe you would use this.

As always be aware of the cost of logging (both disk-space and how sometimes the more you log, the more it can obscure real errors)